# Bind value to a ToolTip Id in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel-body panelscollbar height85">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" runat="server" GridLines="None" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No data found..." AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Company" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Bind("companyname") %>' Text='<%# Bind("_mpce_com") %>' Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to Bind values to this ToolTip Id which is `companyname` from server side,

How can I Bind that value , like following

```
protected void lbtnAddPrftCntr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
      string cmp= ...;

      companyname = cmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: very bad formatting, Kindly format it

Comment: Your binding in markup does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnRowDataBound="grdAdslCompanyAdvisers_RowDataBound"` in your GridView like

```
asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
```

In code behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
            Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_Company");
            lbl.ToolTip = //Your tooltip;
        }
    }
```